# jquery datepicker selects today

Tags: jquery, date, callback, datepicker

"im using an inline JQuery UI datepicker with an onSelect callback function. This function collects selected dates in an array for multiple dates. My problem is that datepicker calls this function on startup with selecting today, and adding it to my array. How can I disable this behaviour? I dont need to know which day is today, don't want to add it to my array automatically...
Thanks in advance for nay help!

Edit: Here's my (pretty simple) onSelect callback as requested:

```
var blocked_days = new Array([..]);
function updateSelected(dateText)
{
    var toAdd = true;
    for (var i in blocked_days)
    {
        if (dateText == blocked_days[i])
        {
            blocked_days[i] = null;
            toAdd = false;
        }
    }
    if (toAdd === true)
        blocked_days[blocked_days.length] = dateText;

    $("#special_offer_blocked_form_blockeddays").val(blocked_days.join());
}
```

Comment: btw it's the recent 1.8.15 jquery ui if it counts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you got your code for the onSelect callback function?

One way around it would be to update the callback function with a check that checks that the date is not today. If it isn't then add the date.

If you can provide an example of your onSelect code I will be more than happy to take a look and add this?

**Update:**

What you could do then is set a simple counter each time the function is called, always ignoring the first call.

```
var number_of_updates = 0;
var blocked_days = new Array([..]);
function updateSelected(dateText)
{
    number_of_updates++;
    if (number_of_updates > 1)
    {
        var toAdd = true;
        for (var i in blocked_days)
        {
            if (dateText == blocked_days[i])
            {
                blocked_days[i] = null;
                toAdd = false;
            }
        }
        if (toAdd === true)
            blocked_days[blocked_days.length] = dateText;
        $("#special_offer_blocked_form_blockeddays").val(blocked_days.join());
    }
}
```

Try that and see if that works?

Comment: That's not a good solution, I want to allow the user to select today. The problem is it's selected automatically on startup, and that's what i want to disable.

Comment: Yes that probably should work, but I didn't do that. For other reason I already made a custom copy of the datepicker js, so hacked into it more deeply and modified not to call _setdate at startup. This way I have the only default values coming from database, and that's what I wanted. I know it's a bit ugly, and can't normally upgrade jquery ui later, but the whole project is in Diem which is heavyli rely on it's bundled jquery so probably won't be upgraded anytime soon... Anyway thanks for the help. Cheers